Right-Click Context Menu Not Appearing in MUI DataTable Component React JS
I’m encountering an issue with a React component using Material-UI (MUI). I have a DataTable component that renders a table with various features, but the right-click context menu does not appear when I right-click on the table rows or cells.
Description:
I’m using the MUI library to create a data table with the following structure:
import { SxProps, Theme, styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import {
    Box,
    Checkbox,
    Paper,
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableCell,
    TableContainer as MuiTableContainer,
    TablePagination,
    TableRow,
    List,
    Typography,
    LinearProgress,
} from "@mui/material";
import {
    ReactNode,
    useState,
    MouseEvent,
    ChangeEvent,
    useMemo,
    useEffect,
} from "react";
import filterFunction, { EFilterType } from "./filter/filter";
import DataFilter, { IFilter } from "./filter/DataFilter";
import Header, { Order } from "./header/Header";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

// Your DataTable component implementation here...

export default DataTable;

Issue:
The right-click context menu is not appearing on the TableRow or TableCell elements. I’ve verified that:
There are no onContextMenu event handlers in my code that prevent the default behavior.
I’ve checked for CSS styles like pointer-events: none or user-select: none, but none are applied.
The issue persists in different browsers and in incognito mode.
Steps Taken:
Tested a Simplified Component: I created a basic table component to see if the right-click menu works there. It did, so the issue is likely specific to my original implementation.
Checked CSS and JavaScript Interference: No styles or global event listeners appear to be affecting the context menu.
Reviewed MUI Documentation: Verified that there are no known issues with right-click behavior in the version of MUI I’m using.
Request:
I’m looking for suggestions or solutions to resolve this issue. Specifically:
Are there any common reasons why a right-click context menu might not appear in MUI components?
Could there be something in my component or its structure that’s causing this issue?
Any other debugging tips or potential fixes?
Thank you for your help!
